# Metallic Versus Covalent Bonding

Tags: bond

Given that a metal's low ionisation energy is often used to explain the metallic bond (as are other factors such as temperature and pressure and possibly a number of other factors), is there any known mathematical and/or empirically proven theory that predicts that under the given set of conditions, a transition will occur from covalent to metallic or vice versa? A metal's proximity to a stable electron shell structure (be it noble gas or complete/semi-complete d- or f- shell structure) is a generic explanation, but (without going into high level mathematical explanations) is there a firmer basis that can make the prediction of that transition, given a set of conditions? If not, is there any research into this issue?

Comment: There surely is a firm basis, but it goes all the way into pretty high-level math, and those who tried to walk around it were never heard of again.

Comment: That's a pretty all-encompassing "dismissal" (for want of a better word) of the issue. Do you have any references that would back that up? Unfortunately I don't have the mathematical knowledge or ability to understand detailed mathematical explanations, but perhaps there is a narrative somewhere which describes, in more simple terms, the efforts taken to address this. To me, it's an area which lies at the core of Chemistry as a science and I find it difficult to believe that it's been placed in the "too hard" basket.